# java.util.Scanner jumps over input requests

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to receive input using `java.util.Scanner`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int bla = scanner.nextInt();
String blubb = scanner.nextLine();
```

But the `nextLine()` command just gets skipped and an empty string is returned. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `nextInt` method does not consume the new line character after the integer so when you call `nextLine` it just reads the new line character immediately following the integer.

**Example**

If you have this input:

```
42\n
foo\n
```

The `readInt` call consumes the `42` but not the new line character:

```
\n
foo\n
```

Now when you call `readLine` it consumes the rest of the first line, which contains only the new line character.

**Solution**

Try discarding the rest of the line after the integer:

```
int bla = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // Discard the rest of the line.
String blubb = scanner.nextLine();
```

Or use `nextLine` consistently to read each line and then parsing the string to an integer yourself:

```
String blaString = scanner.nextLine();
int bla = Integer.valueOf(blaString);
String blubb = scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: +1 I prefer the second option myself, that way you can do some checking for incorrect input, instead of just waiting for the user to stumble into providing an `int` to the scanner.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for this dumb question >_<

Answer (score 4):

It isn't skipped:

```
int bla = scanner.nextInt();
```

Doesn't consume a new line, so your scanner is still on the first line when you hit `Enter` after you input your `int`. Then the scanner sees that it needs to consume the current line (The one where you inputted the `int`) and puts that remainder in `blubb`.

Answer (score -2):

I have had similar issues when my scanner was static. I made a new scanner that was local and it didn't skip over input requests.